# How to suspend and bring a background process to foreground

Tags: shell, job-control, background-process

I have a process originally running in the foreground. I suspended by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, and then resume its running in the background by `bg <jobid>`.

I wonder how to suspend a process running in the background?

How can I bring a background process to foreground?

**Edit:**

The process outputs to stderr, so how shall I issue the command `fg <jobid>` while the process is outputting to the terminal?

Comment: You can still type commands in a terminal that is spewing errors. The text spewed on STDERR doesn't count as input, only the keys you send. It looks confusing on screen but it works.

Comment: @Caleb: Even when the process outputs to stdout, I can still type `fg <jobid>` to make it foreground?

Comment: @Tim: Yes, you can.

Comment: Thanks! I mean, wasted less time, instead of reading the docs.

Answer (score 339, accepted):

As Tim said, type `fg` to bring the last process back to foreground.

If you have more than one process running in the background, do this:

```
$ jobs
[1]   Stopped                 vim
[2]-  Stopped                 bash
[3]+  Stopped                 vim 23
```

`fg %3` to bring the `vim 23` process back to foreground.

To suspend the process running in the background, use:

```
kill -STOP %job_id
```

The SIGSTOP signal stops (pauses) a process
in essentially the same way <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> does.

example: `kill -STOP %3`.

sources:

- [How to send signals to processes in Linux and Unix](http://linuxg.net/how-to-kill-processes-in-linux-and-unix/)
- [How to manage background and foreground jobs](http://linuxg.net/how-to-manage-background-and-foreground-processes).

Comment: signal 19 is `SIGCONT` for me; I use `kill -STOP` and `kill -CONT` in preference to remembering the numbers anyway, but you can check `kill -l` to remind yourself of the numeric values

Comment: The process outputs to stderr, so how shall I issue the command `job` and `fg <jobid>` while the process is outputting to the terminal?

Comment: @Tim Just type the command as you normally would. As long as the job is backgrounded, it is not reading what you type - your shell is. What you type might look broken up to you, but the shell will understand it just fine.

Comment: @AlexWebr: Thanks, it works! (1) Does a background job not accept any input and output including "Ctrl+Z" etc, right? (2) Can a job running in the background be suspended directly? If yes, how? If no, must it be first changed to run in the foreground before it can be suspended?

Comment: _Can a job running in the background be suspended directly_ yes: `kill -STOP %job_id`, as explained

Comment: after suspend a process you can use something like `ps -eo pid,s | grep T | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs kill -SIGCONT` to resume all process

Comment: it would be insanely useful to me if there was a shortcut to typing `kill -STOP %1` such as `st %1` as my typing error rate seems to increase exponentially when the terminal is spewing output and I can't see what I'm typing, so the likelihood I will correctly type `kill -STOP %1` when I'm in a hurry to stop that output is a lot lower than something shorter.

Comment: @Mihael you can write a shell script, a text file, with the top line `!/bin/bash` if that is ypur shell, the second line `kill -STOP $1` where $1 is the first parameter given to this script. Save it wirh file name 'st' in an executable folder like `/usr/local/bin/`. Then make it executable with command `chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/st` and now you can type `st %1` from everywhere.

Comment: Why not use `SIGTSTP` instead? It is the signal used and sent through `ctrl` + `z` from the beginning

Comment: About the first comment - for **macos** signal `19` is `SIGCONT` - for **linux** signal 19 is `SIGSTOP` - for each OS is mandatory execute `kill -l` to see the complete list with the correct codes

Answer (score 56):

This should be true of any shell with job control, which (for the most part) you can take for granted unless dealing with a truly ancient shell.  [It's in the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/jobs.html), so even `dash` supports job control (when run interactively or with `-m`).

### Interactive

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> will suspend the currently foregrounded program
- `bg` will background the most recently suspended program
  (use `bg %2` with the job number, which you can check with `jobs`)
- `fg` will foreground the most recently suspended program

In `zsh`, you can write a key binding to implicitly run `fg` from the prompt via another <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>:

```sh
_zsh_cli_fg() { fg; }
zle -N _zsh_cli_fg
bindkey '^Z' _zsh_cli_fg
```

There's probably also a clever way to implicitly run `bg` upon suspending, but it seems unwise; at least for me, the majority of my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> usage is because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> is failing to break out; I want to follow that with e.g. `kill %1` rather than `bg`, and I certainly don't want to default to killing!  (This logic also extends into why I no longer use this key binding:  If I'm hammering on <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to stop a process, the last thing I want it to do is resume!)

### Non-interactive

If you're in a different shell instance (or a different user, sometimes including `sudo` commands), you likely won't be able to use job numbers.

You can still act on another process once you know its process ID (PID).  You can get the PID with `pgrep …`, or [`ps aux |grep …`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74185/how-can-i-prevent-grep-from-showing-up-in-ps-results/178427#178427) (or from the same shell, `jobs -l`, or `$!`) and you can then run:

```sh
kill -STOP $PID  # suspend
kill -CONT $PID  # continue (resume)
```

If you do not know the process ID and aren't worried about suspending other instances of the process by name, you can pass signals to one of these:

```sh
killall -STOP program_name
pkill -STOP program_name
pkill -f -STOP program_name_or_args
```

A `CONT` signal to a program stopped with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> (and not `bg`'d) will resume its progress (in the foreground), the same as if you were to `fg` it.

### Re: Standard Error

The edit to this question asks about standard error:

> The process outputs to stderr, so how shall I issue the command `fg <jobid>` while the process is outputting to the terminal?

Unless the job in question has components that are backgrounded (or the whole job is backgrounded, perhaps via `kill -CONT`), you shouldn't actually see output while it is suspended.

If it is still outputting data (be it to standard output or standard error), it will certainly make your terminal visually cluttered, but all of that output will be ignored as it is not part of your input.  This might make it harder to know you haven't entered any typos, but (blindly) typing `fg`<kbd>Enter</kbd> should suffice (unless you have multiple jobs and the one in question isn't the most recent, in which case you will indeed need the job descriptor).

If you do need to find the job descriptor, use another terminal to send it the `STOP` signal via the non-interactive methods above.  This should free up your display (perhaps hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> a few times or run `clear` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) so you can then run `jobs` to find the job descriptor and then run `fg %N` where `N` is that number.

Comment: The only problem with pausing and resuming processes is that if you made any connections to some other program (like RabbitMQ for instance), the connection would be lost when you resume.

Comment: @Nav – That's because you didn't run it headless.  In bash and zsh, I believe you merely need to [disown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disown_(Unix)) a backgrounded process.  I prefer to run such tasks with [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup) or a [terminal multiplexer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_multiplexer) like [screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) or [tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux).     You can't pick up a nohup process (just as you can't resume a backgrounded process from a separate connection), but you can connect to a multiplexer.

Comment: It was a background process. I had closed the terminal and then logged in to the server from another terminal.

Comment: Yeah, you can't resume a process from another shell unless it was launched with that in mind.  I recommend screen or tmux for that.

Comment: I believe that if you send a `CONT` signal to a process (job/pipeline) stopped with Ctrl+Z, it will resume in the background, even if you haven't `bg`'d it.

Comment: Why not use `SIGTSTP` instead? It is the signal used and sent through `ctrl` + `z` from the beginning

Comment: @ManuelJordan – You're supposed to use `SIGSTOP` programmatically and `SIGSTP` interactively. `SIGSTOP` cannot be ignored while `SIGSTP` can. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11888074/519360 "What is the difference between SIGSTOP and SIGTSTP?").

Comment: Very nice. I had set up barrier on two new machines and was sharing a keyboard and mouse. I suspended the barrier client program with ctrl+z from the other machine, and immediately lost control of the machine. Oops. Thankfully a quick google got me here. ssh, ps, and kill -CONT worked the magic!

Answer (score 15):

Type `fg` to bring it to the foreground.

Comment: Thanks! The process outputs to stderr, so how shall I issue the command `fg <jobid>` while the process is outputting to the terminal?

Answer (score 4):

1. list jobs with `jobs` command
2. Bring your target job to the foreground with `fg`; e.g.:  `fg %4`
3. Hit `CTRL Z` to suspend
4. To start it running in the background, use bg; e.g.: `bg %4`

Answer (score 0):

Ending a process can be done in several different ways. Often, from a console-based command, sending a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> keystroke (the default interrupt character) will exit the command. This works when process is running in foreground mode.

If a process is running in background mode then first you would need to get its Job ID using the `ps` command and after that you can use kill command to kill the process as follows:

```
$ps -f
UID      PID  PPID C STIME    TTY   TIME CMD
amrood   6738 3662 0 10:23:03 pts/6 0:00 first_one
amrood   6739 3662 0 10:22:54 pts/6 0:00 second_one
amrood   3662 3657 0 08:10:53 pts/6 0:00 -ksh
amrood   6892 3662 4 10:51:50 pts/6 0:00 ps -f
$kill 6738
Terminated
```

Here the `kill` command would terminate the `first_one` process. If a process ignores a regular `kill` command, you can use `kill -9` followed by the process ID as follows:

```
$kill -9 6738
Terminated
```

Comment: While this is true, it is not answering the question...