# Application in terminal still running but not directly accessible

Tags: command-line, process, kill, background-process, job-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to suspend and bring a background process to foreground](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45025/how-to-suspend-and-bring-a-background-process-to-foreground)

I have kind of an odd problem which I haven't encountered before. Here's what I did:

I started an application with `./myApp`.

No command line arguments, no `&` to make it run in background.

Unfortunately, my system froze at some point. No access via the GUI was possible, so I decided to first stop all CPU-intensive tasks. So I brought up a `tty` (Shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> on Ubuntu) and did `kill -STOP pid`, after getting the right `pid` of `myApp` with `top`.

Luckily, after some extra time, the system became unfrozen. So I restarted the process with `kill -CONT pid`.

But here's what I see in the terminal:

```
[2]+ Stopped  ./myApp
```

And now the terminal is in the state as if the application isn't running (i.e. I can do `ls` or whatever I like), but the process manager still reports the application to be running. I'm very glad it does, because I would lose 34 hours of computing time (and yes, it's an extremely bad app; not written by me, of course), since there is no output at all to file.

When the heavy task of the application is finished (expectedly in a couple of hours), I need to enter a specific task inside of the application to make it write to file (it is somewhat of a custom shell prompting for input, so I guess `cin` is in use).

So the question is: How to bring me back to the application such that I see its output and can interact with it? If not possible: is it possible to stream into the app and initiate the required command without restarting the app?

**Update** The application does still output to the exact same terminal.

FYI, as you might need it: I'm running Ubuntu x86 with kernel 3.2.0-36

Comment: I found this question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45025/how-to-suspend-and-bring-a-background-process-to-foreground suggesting to use `fg` to bring back background processes. Might that work in my case?

Comment: Yes indeed. Pressing Ctrl+Z has the same effect as sending a STOP signal: the application is suspended. You can run `fg` to bring it back to the foreground, or `bg` to run it in the background (where it can consume CPU time but not read input).

Comment: @Gilles & jasonwryan: Thanks for improving my question :)

Comment: @Gilles: That's perfect. It seems to work (though the app is busy calculating something, so I might not know 100% until tomorrow). What do you think of closing this as duplicate?

Comment: I already cast the first close vote.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible to reattach a console to a process which has no associated psuedo-tty.

For future scenarios where maintaining a connection to a console is required, try using `screen`.

Screen is a tool designed for interfacing between a specific instance of a shell and the local terminal.  By being a man-in-the-middle, you can detach from the running process and reconnect to it later.  This is useful if you have an unreliable Internet connections if you are using SSH for system management or in instances like yours with a long-running process.

When you open up your terminal (whether in the GUI or on one of the real ttys), just type `screen`.  It should be installed by default in Ubuntu.  Screen will remind you that it is running your default shell and how to find help.  It will then run your login shell and stay back out of the way.

At its most basic usage, you can use `Ctrl-A`, followed by `D` to detach from the current session.  To reconnect to that session, use: `screen -r <complete name of session>`.  If you cannot recall the session name, the `-ls` command switch will provide details as to which sessions are available.

Screen can do so much more that I haven't had much opportunity to use, but years ago, the Digium support staff helped me configure one of their analog POTS interface cards using a reverse SSH connection and Screen in multi-user mode.  This gave them root access to my Asterisk server securely without a need for them to know the password and with the ability for me to audit what was being done.

Comment: any ideas of piping or something like that? I basically only need one command executed. Not seeing the app is totally fine.

Comment: @stefan I second the recommendation of using `screen` for future runs. For this time, while it [is possible](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56298/how-to-screenize-already-running-session) to reattach your program to another terminal (e.g. inside a new Screen session), this is risky — it could kill your application. So don't try it out when the calculation is almost over.

Comment: @Gilles: Fortunately, this will probably be the last time that I have to use this app (I've got the job to build a new version from scratch). But of course, `screen` would be helpful in other situations as well.