# ps aux | grep config vs ps aux | grep "confi[g]"

Tags: grep

I would like to know why `ps aux | grep` includes the `grep` command in the output but `ps aux | grep "confi[g]"` does not.

```
$ ps aux | grep config
root               50   0.0  0.0  2548368   5760   ??  Ss   14Sep16   0:29.27 /usr/libexec/configd
emesa           20534   0.0  0.0  2434840    796 s002  S+    4:41PM   0:00.00 grep config
```

vs.

```
$ ps aux | grep "confi[g]"
root            15776   0.0  0.0  2519824    940   ??  Ss   Tue11AM   0:00.08 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SystemAdministration.framework/XPCServices/writeconfig.xpc/Contents/MacOS/writeconfig
root               50   0.0  0.0  2547320   5740   ??  Ss   14Sep16   0:29.27 /usr/libexec/configd
```

Comment: Because `grep config` matches the line `emesa ... grep config` in `ps aux` output, but `grep confi[g]` doesn't match the corresponding line `emesa ... grep confi[g]` in `ps aux` output.

Comment: See [How can I prevent 'grep' from showing up in ps results?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74185/how-can-i-prevent-grep-from-showing-up-in-ps-results)

Answer (score 2):

Because `grep "confi[g]"` command searches for the *"config"* string and in your second case the `grep "confi[g]"` command does not contain the *"config"* string. It contains the *"confi[g]"* string.

It's a commonly used grep trick to avoid printing the grep command process when searching in `ps` output.

Comment: Commonly used if one doesn't know about `pgrep`  ... (or are stuck using legacy or proprietary unixen)