# Does this grep's regex `[c]ron` mean the same as `cron`?

Tags: grep, regular-expression

From grep's manual

> ```
> ps -ef | grep ’[c]ron’
> ```
>
> If the pattern had been written without the square brackets, it would
>   have matched not only the ps output line for cron, but also the ps
>   output line for grep. Note that on some platforms, ps limits the
>   output to the width of the screen; grep does not have any limit on the
>   length of a line except the available memory

Doesn't `[c]ron` mean the same as `cron`, because `[c]` means a singleton set of alternative characters?

Why does it not match the ps output line for grep?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at the answers found here: [How can I prevent 'grep' from showing up in ps results?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74185/how-can-i-prevent-grep-from-showing-up-in-ps-results)

Answer (score 3):

In term of regular expression, they're the same.

When you use bracket, the output of `ps` for `grep` line will be:

```
ps -ef | grep [c]ron
```

This text will be fed to `grep` standard in, `grep` tries to search for text `cron` which isn't contained in that line, so the line doesn't match.

Without bracket, the line contains text `cron`, so it matches.

Answer (score 0):

In case of grep '[c]ron' the ps output would comprise a literal 
'[' 'c' ']' 'r' 'o' 'n'
And hence the grep '[c]ron' would fail to match the grep command while still
matching the cron job process running.

Whilst the case of grep 'cron' the ps output comprises a literal
'c' 'r' 'o' 'n'
and hence the grep 'cron' would match itself, the grep process, and also
match anyway the cron job process.