# How can I view the full command in top?

Tags: centos, top

I've been using top with `-c` to view the command that started the process. Some commands with long argument lists get cut off though. Is there a way to see these on full? On screen or written to a file is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two possibilities spring to my mind:

1. With `top`, you can use the cursor keys to scroll to the right, providing more space for the `command` column.
2. If you don't need the dynamic output of `top`, try the classic `ps -efw`, perhaps [in combination with grep](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/546271/157411).

Comment: Hah, I never noticed you can scroll horizontally as well as vertically! `ps -efw` is more useful though as I can pipe it through grep and out to files.

Comment: With `top`, the command is getting cut off at 16 characters, `com.apple.wifi.d`, and who knows how much longer this string is, no amount of scrolling helps.  With `ps -efw`, it is still cut off at `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ComerceKit.framework/Versions/A/Resources/store` -- cannot get filename either way.

Comment: `ps -e` did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can (I'm on Linux Mint, CentOS could be different) with `gnome-terminal` do this:

1. Press <kbd>f</kbd>. You will get a list of columns. Navigate through the with arrow keys and press <kbd>Space bar</kbd> to select and unselect which columns to be displayed.

   [image]
2. Use <kbd>q</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> to end.
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>-</kbd> to increase or decrease the font size.