# Why do certain processes keep jumping to higher PIDs?

Tags: process, kill, background-process

Sometimes when my `vscode` hangs up, and I have to force-quit it, it is as though it will not start back up again until I restart my computer. Before shutting the computer down I tried looking for its id because I had a suspicion that it is already running and that's why it wouldn't start a new window up.

```
$ ps aux | grep vscode
rtviii     44456  0.0 0.0   8908   656 pts/0    S+  10:21  0:00 grep ... vscode
$ ps aux | grep vscode
rtviii     44459  0.0 0.0   8908   656 pts/0    S+  10:21  0:00 grep ... vscode
...
```

I discovered that there indeed is this process that looks like `vscode` although the program itself is not functioning (no window, can't open files, just clicked the icon to no effect).

I tried `kill -9`ing the process but the system reports that this `pid doesn't exist`. It seems that every time that I poll for it, it keeps advancing to the higher pid, and that's why I can't pin it down.

Can somebody explain what can be the source of this behavior and how to deal with it?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text, just copy/paste a relevant sample of what you're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process you're seeing from `ps` is the `grep` process you're using to filter for lines containing `vscode`, not `vscode` itself.  Every time you run it, you're running a new instance of `grep` so it gets a new pid.  You can't kill that process because by the time you go to kill it, `grep` has already terminated.

See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74186/90691