# How do you completely exit mysqld_safe or kill it?

Tags: linux, mysql, kill, mysql-connection

I opened mysqld_safe for some reason in Linux but now I can't completely exit or kill it! Closing the terminal didn't help. Then I tried with `kill -9 <process id(s)>` and I killed 2 processes but can't kill the last one.

This is from WSL though, I tried Parrot OS also and the result was same as this one.

```
┌──(dr-ph4ntom� DESKTOP-HSC7AGA)-[~] 
└─$ ps aux | grep mysqld_safe
root       120  0.3  0.0  18036  2804 ?          S   18:31  0:00 sudo mysqld_safe
root       121  0.2  0.0  10460   780 ?          S   18:31  0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
dr-ph4n+   284  0.0  0.0  14292  1224 ? tty2     S   18:32  0:00 grep --color=auto mysqld_safe

┌──(dr-ph4ntom� DESKTOP-HSC7AGA)-[~] 
└─$ sudo kill all mysqld_safe
[sudo] password for dr-ph4ntom:
kill: failed to parse argument: 'all'

┌──(dr-ph4ntom� DESKTOP-HSC7AGA)-[~] 
└─$ sudo killall mysqld_safe                                                                                         1�

┌──(dr-ph4ntom� DESKTOP-HSC7AGA)-[~] 
└─$ ps aux | grep mysqld_safe
root       120  0.0  0.0  18036  2784 ?          S   18:31  0:00 sudo mysqld_safe
root       121  0.0  0.0  10460   780 ?          S   18:31  0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
dr-ph4n+   311  0.0  0.0  14156  1008 ? tty2     R   18:34  0:00 grep --color=auto mysqld_safe

┌──(dr-ph4ntom� DESKTOP-HSC7AGA)-[~] 
└─$ sudo kill -9 120 121 311
kill: (311): No such process

┌──(dr-ph4ntom� DESKTOP-HSC7AGA)-[~] 
└─$ ps aux | grep mysqld_safe                                                                                       1�
dr-ph4n+   320  0.0  0.0  11264   804 ? tty2     R   18:35  0:00 grep --color=auto mysqld_safe
```

Now can you please help me by telling how to solve this problem… I am a newbie both in Linux and StackExchange…

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing appear is the `grep` process, not the actual `mysqld_safe` process running. You already successfully killed the `mysqld_safe` processes.

Try this in terminal instead:

`ps aux | grep "[m]ysqld_safe"`

[And I would be willing to bet nothing will appear. This answer will divine more insight.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/74186/137794)

That being said, grepping the output of `ps` is usually OK, but you would probably be better suited to using `pgrep` instead. A flip through the man pages will make that more clear.