# How to returns the correct character after manipulating the output of ps ax | grep

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, scripting, string

I would like to have some help writing a script (which should works on freebsd where I have sh as default) that should grab a precise character when I do a "**ps ax | grep**" command from the terminal. For example :

```
# ps ax | grep bhyve

12098  -  Is      0:00.00 bhyve: system.pwd (bhyve)
12099  -  Is      0:00.00 bhyve: system.grp (bhyve)
12093  1  IC+    25:11.49 bhyve: vm4 (bhyve)
12557  0  S+      0:00.00 grep bhyve
```

it should returns **4**. The command below returns the wrong values :

```
# ps ax | awk '/bhyve: vm/{print $6}'
vm4
/bhyve:
```

for sure I don't need that it returns **/bhyve:** !

AND :

```
# ps ax | grep vnc

12105  1  S+      0:00.04 vncviewer 0:4
12642  0  S+      0:00.00 grep vnc
```

it should be **4**,but the command below returns also the wrong values :

```
# ps ax | awk '/vncviewer 0/{print $6}'
0:4
/vncviewer
```

even here,it returns **/vncviewer**. I don't want that.

the solution proposed worked in this way :

```
# ps ax | awk '/vncviewer [0]/{print $6}'
0:4

# ps ax | awk '/bhyve: [0]/{print $6}'
0:4
```

Comment: Related: [How can I prevent 'grep' from showing up in ps results?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74185/how-can-i-prevent-grep-from-showing-up-in-ps-results)

Comment: Im not using grep inside the command,but awk.

Comment: @Marietto it’s the same effect, your AWK expression is matching the AWK command.