# How to create a sh script that can give as output the exact string I want using the awk command

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, scripting

I would like to have some help writing a script (which should work on FreeBSD where I have sh as default) that should grab a precise string when I do a `ps ax | grep bhyve` command from the terminal. For example :

```
# ps ax | grep bhyve

43137  -  Is       0:00.00 bhyve: system.pwd (bhyve)
43138  -  Is       0:00.00 bhyve: system.grp (bhyve)
43132  0  IC       2:06.86 bhyve: vm0:18 (bhyve)
43234  1  D+       0:00.00 grep bhyve (csh)
```

when I do :

```
ps ax | awk '/bhyve: vm/{print $6}'
```

it gives :

```
vm0:18
/bhyve:
```

when I do :

```
ps ax | awk '/bhyve: [vm]/{print $6}'
```

it gives :

`vm0:18`

but they are both wrong. The result should be : `0:18`

thanks.

Comment: If I was only running this a few times, or did not care about performance (and if I did then I would do it in Rust) then I would take what I had and pipe it into `sed` to do the last bit.

Comment: something like `ps axo time,command` will get you exactly the columns you want, in the order you want them in. but I'd proably write it in C if I used the program a lot

Comment: You're still doing the same thing we showed you how to fix when you asked this question a couple of days ago at https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/715477/133219, i.e. using a regexp that matches itself. Please read and do what it shows in the question yours was closed as a dup of.

Comment: First of all,the solution proposed didn't work well and 2) it hasn't explained well. So,I tried to apply it by myself,but I've realized that it didn't work well maybe because to hide part of the string is a solution which works only in some circumstances. For these reasons,I've opened another post and I've found a more precise solution. I suggest you to give more detailed explanation when you sugggest something and a more accurate support,otherwise one looks for a better solution. maybe you are sure to talk with an experienced user and you give a fast reply,but it's not always true.

Comment: I suggest you to don't close one question even if it is closer to the other one,because as I said,the trick to hide part of the string is not a solution which works in a lot of conditions,people should understand this. It's a good idea that an alternative solution is kept alive when the first one does not work. To have different alternative solutions should be considered a good situation. To close one post only because it's close to another one (but not the same,because I've got an answer that works differently),is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code may work (stripping first two symbols from the string):

```
ps ax | awk '/bhyve: [vm]/{print substr($6,3)}'
```

Comment: 0:18. it works. very thanks. if ps ax | awk '/bhyve: vm/{print $6}' would give vm0:9,how your script should be modified ?

Comment: it works even if the starting input is vm0:9,that's good.