# Why does ps aux | grep <something> return extra hit

Tags: ps

Let's say I want to know the PID of kate editor that is currently running (kate is just an example, it works as described for many programs). So, I execute `ps aux | grep kate`.

Here is the output:

```
seifert     35523  0.0  0.2 448724 25144 ?        Sl   08:56   0:33 /bin/kate -b
seifert   1499179  0.0  0.0  12196   656 pts/0    S+   21:52   0:00 grep --color=auto kate
```

The first line is what I expect to see. But what is the second one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you type `ps aux|grep kate`, this will launch `grep kate`, `grep kate` will be seen as `grep kate` (or something more complex if you have some aliases like in this example). And `grep kate` will select the corresponding line because there is a `kate` substring.

If you want to get `kate` process from the list of processes BEFORE the grep command, `pgrep` can be the command you need.

EDIT: Even `pgrep pgrep` doesn't find itself.

Answer (score 5):

That's because it return one line for the process you are searching for AND for the command you just entered: `grep kate`.

So, if you want to have just one response use this command:

```
ps -fp $(pgrep -f '<your_search>')
```

`pgrep -f` searches the PID of a process based on its launching full command (parameters included).

Answer (score 2):

Quoting Wayne Werner's answer:

> By putting the brackets around the letter and quotes around the string you search for the regex, which says, "Find the character 'f' followed by 'nord'."
> But since you put the brackets in the pattern 'f' is now followed by ']', so grep won't show up in the results list. Neato!

> With [f] i don't get the last line with the grep command it self in the output right diff: beetwen "ps aux | grep firefox" and "ps aux | grep [f]irefox" is the last output line

[How can I prevent 'grep' from showing up in ps results?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74185/how-can-i-prevent-grep-from-showing-up-in-ps-results)

If you don't want so see the last grep command you be called like `ps aux | grep 'kate'` process/command in the process list you can use

```
ps aux | grep '[k]ate'
```

you can use this brackets `[]` with every command/process you searching

`ps aux | grep '[c]ommand' or '[p]rocess'`

You can also use, to get only the pid

`pidof kate`

or

`pgrep kate`

or

`ps -ef | grep [k]ate`